# openshift with socket.io, npm install couldn't read dependancies

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

Whilst trying to build a node.js server with socket.io on openshift the following errors occur.

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-753.el7xtsync.x86_64 
npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs4/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs4   /root/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! file /opt/app-root/src/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib/parse'
npm ERR! File: /opt/app-root/src/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

However the code runs fine on my local machine, without any errors

I use the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "socket_thing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "To make a server plugin for superpowers",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Is there any reason why the way the dependencies are handled differently on openshift, as that seems to be where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that using the newest version of express

```
"express": "^4.16.2"
```

in the package.json solved the problem.